# extraction with scala regex

Tags: scala

I have the following string as input :

`val input="               12    BANANAPPLESTRAWBERRY                   LOC 8(05).`               "
And I want to parse this string using Regex and pattern matching

The wanted output shall look like:

```
val output=" BANANAPPLESTRAWBERRY         Int(5)"
```

I wrote the following function:

```
val rega = """(.{6}[^*])(\s*)(\d*)(\s*)(\S*)(\s*)(\S{4})(8\(0*(\d+)\))(.*)""".r
  def functionEx(s: String, regb: Regex): String = {
    s match {
      case regb(start,space, nb, space2, naame, space3, loc, vartype, length, end) => name + "(Int"+ length +")"
      case _ => ""
    }
  }
```

When I call this function on my input : `functionEx(input,rega)` I got the empty string :  `""` 
Any help with please

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you really need all the spaces and all the separators? Wouldn't it be easier to capture only the stuff that you actually need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you tried there with that regex. It captures all kind of groups that are seemingly mostly irrelevant (whitespace, full stop in the end). It also contains parts like `\S{4}` that don't seem to match anything, and magic number like `9` that doesn't appear in the input string. So, obviously, it doesn't match the input, so the second case in the pattern matching applies, and a `""` is returned.

Try this instead:

```
val input="               12    BANANAPPLESTRAWBERRY           LOC 8(05). "

import scala.util.matching.Regex

val rega = """^(.{6})\s+(\d*)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+8\(0*(\d+)\)\s*\.\s*""".r

def functionEx(s: String, regb: Regex): String = {
  s match {
    case regb(start, nb, name, loc, length) => name + " Int("+ length +")"
    case _ => ""
  }
}

println(functionEx(input ,rega))

println(functionEx(input ,rega))
```

It produces the following output:

```
BANANAPPLESTRAWBERRY Int(5)
```

Comment: I made a mistake it is not 9 but rather 8 so the uses regex is rather : val rega = """(.{6}[^*])(\s*)(\d*)(\s*)(\S*)(\s*)(\S{4})(8\(0*(\d+)\))(.*)""".r

Comment: @ Andrey Tyukin: The 8 is an indicator for me may you please include it in your regex